# C++ algorithmic code won't compile correctly

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm doing this code for a project to evaluate an algorithmic equation, if it doesn't have a "a" in the string of the algorithmic equation I'm given, I'm supposed to return the value and return false. If it does have "a" I'm supposed to return value = 0 and return true. This is all being done a in a bool function.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool Evaluate(const string& expression, int& value){
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    string valueA;
    string valueB;
    string valueC;
    string valueD;
    string valueE;
    int y;
    int z;
    unsigned int i;
    stringstream x;
    int szz;
    string alg;

    if(!expression.find('a')) {

        szz = expression.size();
        alg = expression.copy(0, szz);

        for (i = 0; i <= szz; ++i) {
            alg.find_first_of('*/%');
            if (isdigit(alg[i] - '*')) {
                a = alg.find('*');
                y = a - 1;
                z = a + 1;
                valueA = alg.substr(y, z);
                a = stoi(valueA);
                x << a;
                valueA = x.str();
                alg.replace(y, 2, valueA);
            }

            if (isdigit(alg[i] - '/')) {
                b = alg.find('/');
                y = b - 1;
                z = b + 1;
                valueB = alg.substr(y, z);
                b = stoi(valueB);
                x << b;
                valueB = x.str();
                alg.replace(y, 2, valueB);
            }
      
        value = stoi(alg);
        return false;
    }

    else{
        value = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get the correct values and the correct true/false. Currently if there's an a in the equation I get the result correct as 0, but not the evaluate result (true/false). The opposite happens if there's no a in the equation, I get the evaluate result correct as false but not the actual correct value.

Comment: What is purpose of `if(!alg.find('a'))` that is always false with the empty `alg`? 1. `find` does not return bool. 2. You might want to use `expression` instead of `alg`.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of find clarify if a is in the equation?

Comment: I recommend reading C++ books and function manuals on https://cppreference.com Using string::find is good if it's used properly w/o guessing or false expectations.

Comment: Can you please reduce the example a bit, so that we can see where the problem occurs. You cannot expect that we read so many lines of code.

Comment: Side note: Declaring many variables at the beginning of a scope is one of the worst things a coder can do. Makes those variables hard to understand. How are others supposed to know which variable is used where and for what purpose? It makes the code ambiguous.

Comment: @habrewning All the code from if till else does not run.

Comment: @silver02 I said expression instead of alg, not find. You made your code uncompilable.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm does a lot more than what you write. The goal, apparently, is not to look for `a` but rather to evaluate entire math expressions.

Furthermore, your algorithm is flawed in many ways, I just point out some here:

1. The `if` in

   ```
   string alg;
   if(!alg.find('a')) {
   ```

   is always true since there never is an 'a' in `alg` since `alg` is created empty just the line before.
2. This does just copy an entire string

   ```
   szz = expression.size();
   alg = expression.copy(0, szz);
   ```

   and is 100% equivalent to `string alg = expression;`
3. You don't need a for loop in

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= szz; ++i) {
      alg.find_first_of('*/%');
   ```

   since the `find_first_of` does what it advertises and already loops over the string itself.
4. You just discard the return value of `alg.find_first_of('*/%');`. You want to write `int operator_position = alg.find_first_of('*/%');`, then you know that at `alg[operator_position]` there is one of `*/%`.
5. You have several lines of this type

   ```
   isdigit(alg[i] - '*')
   ```

   but it appears to be obvious to me that this is very much not what you want. From the logic of your code, I understand you need to know if a sub-string in alg is a digit (or still an expression containing +-*/%). Your statement only acts on a single char
6. Other potential problems.

You actual problem you describe can be solved easily:

```
bool Evaluate(const string& expression, int& value){
    if (expression.find('a')!=string::npos) {
       // whatever it means to "contain the value" ????
       return false;
    }
    value = 0;
    return true;
}
```

*But* this will serve no reasonable purpose and I am sure you are really just mis-representing the actual problem posed....

Here is what I would infer as an actual related problem and algorithm: Q: evaluate math expressions from a string and return the answer. Thus, "2*6+4-6/2" should return 13. If you want to achieve this, you need iterative function calling of `Evaluate` and I would propose `double Evaluate(const string& expression)`:

- you evaluate if your string contains any of `+-` if yes, you iteratively evaluate the two independent parts (using `expression.substr(start,length)`) proceeding as well as preceeding the `operator_position` (see above for a hint). You then either add or subtract the two results depending on `+` or `-`. You return the result.
- (else) you evaluate if your string contains any of `*/%` and if yes, you iteratively evaluate the two independent sub-strings proceeding and preceeding the `operator_position`. You either multiply, divide or modulo the two values and return the result.
- if none of the two above, then the remaining expression must be a `number` and you convert the string into a double (`std::stod(expression)`) and return it.

This iterative algorithm will *magically* correctly evaluate any math expression.